# How to investigate iOS crash with error NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-50 "query missing class name"

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

Our app, released via TestFlight, is currently experiencing crashes for a small number of users, and the crash is very difficult to investigate. It happens on iOS 9 and 9.1, and we've seen it on several different iPhones. We've tested all these devices and OS versions so that doesn't appear to be the issue.

To debug the issue I've tried to check the device logs, and here is all we get:

```
securityd[93] <Error>:  securityd_xpc_dictionary_handler Roger[1287] copy_matching Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-50 "query missing class name" UserInfo={NSDescription=query missing class name}
Roger[1287] <Error>:  SecOSStatusWith error:[-50] Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-50 "query missing class name" UserInfo={NSDescription=query missing class name}
SpringBoard[58] <Warning>: HW kbd: Failed to set (null) as keyboard focus
com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (UIKitApplication:im.rgr.RogerApp[0x24fe][1287]) <Notice>: Service exited due to signal: Trace/BPT trap: 5
diagnosticd[84] <Error>: unable to find offset 0x99c5ba5c in shared cache for arch 'arm64'
SpringBoard[58] <Warning>: Application 'UIKitApplication:im.rgr.RogerApp[0x24fe]' crashed.
UserEventAgent[26] <Warning>: 2808550521498: id=im.rgr.RogerApp pid=1287, state=0
```

Once I try to run the app via Xcode with Debug or Production (exact same code as what was released) the error no longer happens. So it only seems to happen specifically when the app is released via TestFlight.

Does anyone have any idea how to debug this issue?

Comment: Am also facing the same crash error, Can you please post the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Just in case this helps, I saw this error in the logs when trying to open an app signed with an Enterprise provisioning profile. I did not see the usual warning about trying to open an untrusted app; I have no idea why.

The fix was to go into Settings -> General -> Device Management (or Profiles & Device Management), and then under the Enterprise apps section, select the organisation and on the next screen choose to trust the profile. Documented in https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204460

Answer (score -1):

This issue turned out to be due to a framework accidentally being marked as required instead of optional, which would crash iOS 8 devices. (We originally thought it was happening on iOS 9+ devices as well, but it turned out it was iOS 8.4.)

Here's a screenshot of the corrected settings:
[image]

Comment: Can you give a bit more info?  There's *very little* out there about this error, and I'd like to have a better understanding.  How does marking framework as required, vice optional, cause a runtime crash (after hours of app running) ?  Thanks!

Comment: @Blixt didn't you tell that it was causing crashes on iOS9+. Why now are you deactivating `WatchConnectivity` and the other?

Comment: Please read the answer text above the picture which answers your questions. The reason it crashes on iOS 8 is because a required framework that isn't supported on that version of the OS will crash the app. Making it optional means the OS will only attempt to load the framework if it's referenced by the app (so put all your uses of the framework into `if #available(iOS 9.0, *)` blocks).